# Timelapse only shows single year in Google Earth Engine (ERA5 Daily agg.)

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap, cartopy

I am trying to make a yearly timelapse of ERA5 Daily aggregates (precipitation) using cartopy but the output gif and images generated show the plots of single year. I am trying to extract the images and make a gif from 1981 to 2000 period. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/8c8A9X75

```
import ee
import geemap
import os
from geemap import cartoee

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

lon = [lat here]
lat = [lon here]

start_date = 1981
end_date = 2000

point = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)
years = ee.List.sequence(start_date, end_date)

def get_image(years):
    start = ee.Date.fromYMD(start_date, 1, 1)
    end = ee.Date.fromYMD(end_date, 12, 31)
    
    image = (ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY")
            .filterBounds(point)
            .filterDate(start, end)
            .select('total_precipitation')
            .first()
    )
    return ee.Image(image)

collection = ee.ImageCollection(years.map(get_image))

vis_params = {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 0.1,
    'palette': ['#FFFFFF', '#00FFFF', '#0080FF', '#DA00FF', '#FFA400', '#FF0000']
}

image = ee.Image(collection.first())
geomPoly = ee.Geometry.BBox(10, 10, 10, 10); #dummy coordinates of BB
region = image.clip(geomPoly)
Map.addLayer(region, vis_params, 'First Image')
Map.setCenter(lon, lat, 4)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
selection = [10, 10, 10, 10]
ax = cartoee.get_map(region, region=selection, vis_params=vis_params)
ax.set_title(label="South Asia")

cartoee.get_image_collection_gif(
    ee_ic = collection,
    out_dir=os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/timelapse"),
    out_gif="animation.gif",
    vis_params=vis_params,
    region=selection,
    fps=3,
    mp4=True,
    plot_title="South Asia | Precipitation",
    date_format="YYYY-MM-dd",
    fig_size=(10, 8),
    dpi_plot=100,
    file_format="png",
    verbose=True
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without running this myself, I assume the problem is `get_image()`. This will be executed for every year in `years` (sort of - on EE servers): `years.map(get_image)`. For starters, you have named the argument `years`, while it will be invoked with a single years. That maybe points to some confusion how `map()` works? In any case, you're not using that argument at all. You probably want to do this:

```
def get_image(year):
    year = ee.Number(year) # must be cast to the correct type
    start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
    end = ee.Date.fromYMD(year.add(1), 1, 1) # end is exclusive
    ...
```